# wordpress, get second newest post

Tags: wordpress, get, posts

I need to get second newest post from wordpress, and I cant do this. I found I lot of tutorials how to get several newest posts, but no how to get only one post that is second in the order (or fifth, or tenth).

I have something like this:

```
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                   <?php if(get_posts()[1] == true) : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content-second-row', ( post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'post-formats' ) ? get_post_format() : get_post_type() ) ); ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

But, of course it is not working. I tried to get get_post().length. I know, unfortunately I can't use posts id, because there is no one by one.

Please, help me.

Of course, I try to finde something in wordpress codex

Comment: use wp_get_recent_posts method

Comment: It works great for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
get_posts( array('posts_per_page'   => 5,'offset' => 1,))
```

You can change offset to any number you want.